# Extracting values from params hash: smart way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have the following code in my controller:

```
login = params[:user_registration][:login]
password = params[:user_registration][:password]
email = params[:user_registration][:email]
```

It's too verbose and ugly, any smarter way to extract the keys I need?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on what you're trying to do? If for instance you're trying to create a new `User` record, typical we do the following: `User.new(params[:user])`. I guess in your case it would be `User.new(params[:user_registration])` - not entirely sure why though.

Comment: Do you have a UserRegistration class and was the form built from it?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this?

```
login, password, email = params[:user_registration].values_at :login, :password, :email
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Btw, what about `user.name, user.password, user.email = params[:user_registration].values_at :name, :password, :email`? Any way to skip repeating `user` in left part of assignment?

Comment: Personally, I usually write a set_from_params method or something to that order for that kind of stuff. Within it, do something like `hash.each { |key, val| __send__("#{key}=", val) }`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth your while encapsulating the attributes in a class, if indeed you don't already have one. Perhaps a UserRegistration class? Then you could do;

`@new_user = UserRegistration.new(params[:user_registration])`

This would make passing the attributes over to models and views more convenient too.

Answer (score 0):

Package them together, and only overwrite when needed

```
attrs = params[:user_registriation]
attrs.email.downcase! # Only overwrite on selected attr when needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do it this way:

```
user_params = [:login, :password, :email]

User.new(params.select {|v| user_params.include?(v)})
```

This passes only the parameters that are necessary for creating the model and it's clear to read.